# Is there a way to use xterm on chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm using Secure Shell on chrome which is great. Now the only problem is that I cannot use xterm. Is there a way to install X11? Thanks!

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/708811/can-i-use-a-chromebook-as-a-ssh-workstation

Answer (score 6):

For traditional Chromebooks, the [nassh secure shell extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?hl=es-419) supports [ports forwarding (tunneling)](https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/HEAD/nassh/doc/FAQ.md#Can-I-forward-ports) but not support X11 forwarding.
Instead, if you can install software in the remote computer, you may try a VNC client or the [Google Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp).

**Using Android Apps**

Recently. some Chromebooks can run Android apps. If you have [one of these manchines](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-android-apps), you may try one of the X-windows apps for android.

- For instance, there are the [Darkside X Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.darkside.XServer), [XServer XSDL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=x.org.server) and [QVD Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theqvd.android.client&hl=es) in the Play Store.

**Using Crouton**

Some developers use their Chromebook in "developer mode" and [install crouton Ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/). The Crouton defines a chroot-based Linux environment that may run X-windows.

- Crouton may run X-windows in two modes: using [Xiwi (X11 in a window)](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/crouton-in-a-Chromium-OS-window-%28xiwi%29), that runs the X in a Chrome window, or using XORG in a different virtual screen. A [tutorial video for installing Crouton](https://chromeunboxed.com/install-native-apps-on-your-chromebook-with-ubuntu-linux/) was published by chromeunboxed (see the X-window starting at 18:00 minute)..
- Some time ago, David Crumpton prublished a [guide to use the X windows of the Chromebook](https://davidcrumpton.blogspot.com.co/2013/03/cromebook-x-windows-setup-using-crouton.html). If you hacve some problems, there are some hints on the library paths and variables that you may check.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Enable Linux beta mode. The preinstalled linux terminal on chromeos is embeded with xclient. Make sure the machine that you ssh into has x11 forwarding enabled.

Simple test:

```
ssh -X username@your.server.ip
xeyes
```

Comment: This is more relevant to now on newer Chromebooks.

Answer (score 1):

So far, there is only secure shell app that allows ssh. But xterm is not available yet.

Answer (score 1):

xpra-html5 can let you create multiple x sessions on the target server and show their output in your browser's tabs.
it's much more than cool!
the performance is good and the developer is very supportive.

Answer (score 0):

The Chromebrew package manager has an [xterm package](https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew/blob/3f5240c5891907c78c33ef1932a71da24f6aaa17/packages/xterm.rb) available.

Using [Sommelier](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform2/+/master/vm_tools/sommelier/) quite a few graphical applications are available to use on Chromebooks if you don't like Crostini/termina (the official Linux container support available on some devices).